# Setup Kiosk—convert Upstart to Systemd

Tags: systemd, services, upstart, kiosk

Following this great tutorial https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/ which unfortunately is for ubuntu 14.04, I have started out to do that using ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

All in all I could reproduce everything from the tutorial and to sum up:

```
apt install --no-install-recommends xorg openbox chromium-browser pulseaudio


#/opt/kiosk.sh
xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
start-pulseaudio-x11

chromium-browser --kiosk --no-first-run  'http://thepcspy.com'
```

Running this:

```
root@test: sudo -u kioskuser startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --
```

Starts the browser, just as I like to have it, so everything fine until here. But now I would like to install that thing as a **systemd service**, so I basically have to convert:

```
start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [06]

console output
emits starting-x

respawn

exec sudo -u kioskuser startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --
```

to a `/etc/systemd/system/kiosk.service` file, what I already did:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kiosk Launcher

[Service]
User=kioskuser
ExecStart=/opt/kiosk.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it is not working and gives me that:

[image]

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the package `xserver-xorg-legacy` was missing. Additionally `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.conf` had to include:

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

Finally I needed to delete `~/.XAuthority` for the »kioskuser«.